# Which ellipses settle to 1-point contacts within a snow-globe circle?

Tags: geometry, classical-mechanics, curvature

Suppose you have a solid ellipse with axes $a$ and $b$, $(x/a)^2 + (y/b)^2 = 1$,
confined inside a unit-radius circle.
You shake the circle like a snow globe, and the ellipse settles to
the bottom under gravity, assume with frictionless ellipse-circle contact.

---

[image: EllipseInCircle]

---

> ***Q***. For which $a$ and $b$ will the ellipse settle to a single point of contact?

I would especially appreciate an answer that avoids excessive calculations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the curvature radius of the ellipse at $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ to be smaller than the curvature radius of the circle.

That is:

$\dfrac{a^2}{b}<1$

EDIT: the general expression of the curvature radius of an ellipse of equation $x=a \cos t$, $y=b \sin t$ is $R_c=\dfrac{a^2}{b}(1-e^2\cos^2 t)^{\frac 32}$, with $e=\sqrt{1-(\frac{b}{a})^2}$ being the excentricity of the ellipse.

You have also directly from this that the radius of curvature at $0$ is $\dfrac{b^2}{a}$

Comment: The other way round? - the curvature of the ellipse is greater than that of the circle (the radius of curvature is smaller).

Comment: @Paul Since English is not my first language, I did an early mistake by naming it curvature, when I was thinking of radius of curvature. I edited the post. But the result was already the good one.

Comment: And could you add for completeness: Why is that expression the curvature?

Comment: @Martigan. I got that too.

Comment: Also note that using implicit differentiation $y'' = \frac{b}{a^2}$ at y = -b since $y' = 0$ at that point. Then, also since $y' = 0$, the curvature is simply the modulus of $y''$. This curvature must be greater than r, the radius of the circle, which @Martigan has taken to be 1.

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke: The curvature at a point $q$ is also equal to the reciprocal of the 2nd derivative, after transforming the coordinate system by a rigid motion of the plane so that $q$ is the origin and the curve is tangent to the $x$-axis.